# MS Access multiple table updates from flat excel

Tags: sql, excel, database, ms-access-2010

I am trying to do a relatively common task I think. I have a flat Excel file from which I have created a normalized Access DB. Now I want to take in new Excel files with same format and populate the various Master Data tables and transaction table. The structure is similar to this: The Excel file has columns for Customer, Product and Quantity. The Access DB has Master Data tables for Customer (ID, Customer_Name and Address columns) and Product (ID, Product_Name and Color columns). I want to search the new Excel file for new Customers and new Products and then add them to their respective Master Data tables and auto-assign them a new incremental ID number. Then I want to create records in the Orders table that match the rows in the Excel file but use the auto-assigned IDs. As it may be obvious the whole point here is to maintain the normalized structure while automating the task of building the database via importing Excel sheets generated elsewhere. Am I crazy or is this kind of common? Please help! You’re the best if you can!

Comment: The Excel file is ambiguous-- does it have Customer-Name, or Customer-ID, or Customer-Address, or Customer-Phone??? ditto for Product..???  If Excel has "names" of these, what are the odds of typo and misspellings?  Creating new rows then becomes automating garbage.  The Excel does not seem to have Customer-Address, or Product-Color and is insufficient to create a proper row.  We would need a larger view of the system problem that you are facing in order to recommend a solution.  Putting the database on line at the fingertips of each person currently typing in excel might be a better solution.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I was being more general with my analogy to an "Orders" table. I just first want to take columns from an Excel file and put them in different tables if the value doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to link to the Excel file, use an Unmatched Query to see which records are new, and add them as required. Something like this should get you pointed in the right direction:

```
Sub sGetCustomerData(strXLFile As String)
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsCustomer As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsAdd As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "tblTemp"
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "tblTemp", strXLFile, True
    Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
    strSQL = "SELECT T.Customer " _
        & " FROM tblTemp AS T LEFT JOIN tblCustomer AS C ON T.Customer=C.Customer_Name " _
        & " WHERE C.Customer_Name IS NULL;"
    Set rsCustomer = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    If Not (rsCustomer.BOF And rsCustomer.EOF) Then
        Set rsAdd = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblCustomer WHERE 1=2;")
        Do
            With rsAdd
                .AddNew
                !Customer_Name = rsCustomer!Customer
                .Update
            End With
            rsCustomer.MoveNext
        Loop Until rsCustomer.EOF
    End If
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rsAdd.Close
    rsCustomer.Close
    Set rsAdd = Nothing
    Set rsCustomer = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "tblTemp"
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 7874   '   temp table not found to delete
            Resume Next
        Case 7889   '   file does not exist
        Case Else
        MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sGetCustomerData", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    End Select
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

You may run into issues with data in the Excel file being duplicated with slightly different spellings - "Mr J Smith"/"Mr J. Smith"/"Mr John Smith" for example.

Regards,